# PHP Cookie not set when sent through POST-Request from Angular

Tags: php, angular, cookies

I want to set a basic cookie, when the user accepts them. Therefore I am using Angular with PHP-Backend. Angular runs on localhost:4200 and PHP via XAMPP on localhost. The cookie is set when I just separate the "set cookie"-part to the end of the file. When I perform the API-Call, the if-conditions work too because I get the right response-messages. However, no cookie is set, when I perform the API-Call through Angular.

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$cookies = json_decode($json, true);

$cookie_name = 'allCookies';

if ($cookies['allCookies'] == true) {
    $cookie_value = 'set';
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 365), '/');
    $message = "Cookies gesetzt!";
} else {
    $cookie_value = 'unset';
    unset($_COOKIE["allCookies"]);
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() - 3600, '/');
    $message = "Cookies entfernt!";
}

$response = array(
    "message" => $message,
);

// setcookie($cookie_name, 'set', time() + (86400 * 365), '/'); When I outcomment this line and run the php in the browser, a cookie is set correctly

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: can you also share your angular code. Because you are using two different ports, you have to open your api address in your browser to see the cookies in the dev tools of your browser.

Comment: @Alimo which part(s) do you need to see?

Comment: I have tried your code locally and with postman, it works just fine when I send {"allCookies":"set"} as the request body, it returns the "Cookies gesetzt!" message and also sends a Set-Cookie header with the value allCookies=set; expires=Sat, 11-Sep-2021 18:32:20 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/ 
There should be a problem with your Angular app, maybe you are checking cookie on port 4200 or you are not sending the request body correctly.

Comment: @Alimo I have uploaded a production build and there it works fine. The message I receive as a response from the post-request is correct so I think the problem is in the php or the port configuration